# React - update multiple components' status when click on third component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update more than 5 components' status after a button is clicked. I'm now putting all the status and event handlers in App.js. For example,

```
// MyButton.js
export const MyButton = (props) => {
  <button type='button' onClick={props.onClick}>Click Me!</button>
}

// Component1.js
export const Component1 = ({ name }) => {
    return (
      <h1>{name}</h1>
    );
}

// Component2.js
export const Component2 = ({ name }) => {
    return (
      <h1>{name}</h1>
    );
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { name1: '', name2: '' };
    this.changeNames = this.changeNames.bind(this);
  }

  changeNames() {
    this.changeComponent1Name();
    this.changeComponent2Name();
  }

  changeComponent1Name() {
    this.setState({ name1: 'name1' });
  }

  changeComponent2Name() {
    this.setState({ name2: 'name2' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyButton onClick={this.changeName} />
      <Component1 name={this.state.name1} />
      <Component2 name={this.state.name2} />
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The code becomes more complicated as more components I have to update when the button is clicked. I'd like to put the status and event handlers in each components so the code can be more readable. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps a loop?

Comment: why you create two method changeComponent1Name & changeComponent2Name just create one method for both changeComponentsName(){this.setState({name:'name1', name:'name2'})}

Answer (score 0):

just loop over state:

```
  changeNames() {
    let newState = {...this.state}
    for (var stateProp in newState) {
       //add here your logic depending on prop name/for every prop
    }
  }
```